# database.yml rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

por que me sale error?
Estoy haciendo el deploy para producion. gracias

**database.yml**

```
 production:
     adapter: mysql2
     encoding: utf8
     database: trabajo
     username: root
     password: 987654
     host: localhost
     port: 3306
```

rails db:create

**error **

```
rails aborted!

ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]

o

/home/administrador/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:246:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

**asi  era  antes**

```
  default: &default
     adapter: sqlite3
        pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
        timeout: 5000

     development:
      <<: *default
       database: db/development.sqlite3


    test:
      <<: *default
       database: db/test.sqlite3

    production:
       <<: *default
        database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: @Gerry hola  usted sabe algo sobre esto? me puedes ayudar seria bueno, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el archivo *database.yml* debes configurar la base de datos para cada ambiente, lo común es tener `development`, `test` y `production`.

Cuando trabajas localmente el ambiente por defecto es `development`, por lo que *Rails* busca la configuración de la base de datos para ese ambiente, sin embargo únicamente tienes la configuración de `production`.

Entonces, para resolver el error, solo agrega la configuración de la base de datos `development`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: trabajo
  username: root
  password: 987654
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

---

Si tienes valores duplicados en diferentes ambientes entonces puedes utilizar `default` para evitar escribir dos veces lo mismo, por ejemplo:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  port: 3306

development:
  <<: *default
  database: trabajo_development
  username: root
  password: 987654
  host: localhost

production:
  <<: *default
  database: trabajo
  username: dbadmin
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] %>
  host: servidor_produccion
```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto `rails db:create` se ejecuta en el entorno de desarrollo (development). Para indicarle que ejecute la acción en otro entorno tienes que indicar el entorno en la variable RAILS_ENV en el mismo comando el cual quedaria así:

```
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```